# Auto login with curl

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to auto access "http://games.espn.go.com/fba/clubhouse?leagueId=xxxxx&teamId=8&seasonId=2014" by using:

```
$ebay_user_id = "username"; 
$ebay_user_password = "password"; 
$cookie_file_path = "crawler\ebay_login\cook";

$LOGINURL = "http://games.espn.go.com/fba/signin";
$POSTFIELDS = 'e=0&cookieDomain=.go.com&multipleDomains=true&username='. $ebay_user_id .'&password='. $ebay_user_password;

$reffer = "http://games.espn.go.com/fba/signin?redir=http%3A%2F%2Fgames.espn.go.com%2Ffba%2Fclubhouse%3FteamId%3D8%26leagueId%xxxxxx%26seasonId%3D2014"; 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$LOGINURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$POSTFIELDS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $reffer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

I am using a example that was working for ebay. Where should i focus to make this work for espn? With my example it gets redirected to a page that says "Invalid Login. Please try again."

Comment: maybe there is a hash that validate the login

Comment: I wasnt able to find anything hash related. Any other options? ESPN replied that it should be done.